# Password AutoFill save password SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, autofill

Good day.

I'm trying to implement a login page in SwiftUI, but I'm unable to figure out how to make the application prompt the user to save their credentials after a successful login.

This is the code for the input fields.

```
        TextField("Phone number", text: $phoneNumber)
            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
            .textContentType(.username)

        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            .keyboardType(.asciiCapable)
            .textContentType(.password)
```

On success, an environment variable changes, and the parent component will stop rendering the login page.

I've enabled the "Autofill Credential Provider" entitlement.

What I am trying to achieve is use of the native "password manager" in 
iOS, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill.

[image: password autofill prompt on iOS]

When the user would submit their credentials and successfully authenticate, they should be shown a prompt like the one above, asking them if they want to save the password they used to sign in.

Comment: I am not sure about your question, but if I understood well you could make that with an alertView after the succesfull login, or with a switch named "remember me?" that is turned off by default on the login page, which could be turned on by the user before logging in.

Comment: Apologies @stacks, I've updated the question with more details now. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: No problem, it's clear now. I will try to answer your question

Comment: @FredrikA. Did you found the solution?

Comment: @iDroid I did not, sadly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with password autofill is not the UIKit/SwiftUI implementation. To get support in your app, the most important things to get right are:

1. Add "Associated Domains" capability to your app and set "Domains" to `webcredentials:example.com` (replacing `example.com` with a domain you actually own and have access to!).
2. On your website (accessible under the given domain) place a file named `apple-app-site-association` into your public accessible root directory in a folder `.well-known`.
   You can test access using the command `curl https://www.example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`. (Yes, HTTPS must be enabled and have a valid certificate!)
3. The content of the `apple-app-site-association` must reference your Apple Developer Team ID and the bundle identifier of your app as follows: (Team ID is "A1BC23REUG" and bundle identifier is "com.example.signin-playground")

```json
{
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [ 
      "A1BC23REUG.com.example.signin-playground"
    ]
  }
}
```

4. Mark the input fields in SwiftUI using the appropriate `textContentType` modifier.

I have written a small example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pd95/4193df6e54a754bc84aa0c239f65c16f) which I successfully tested.

If autofill is not working (e.g. you get only an unspecific password completion dialog), you normally have to check the bundle/team identifier and the in the `apple-app-site-association` file. If you changed something in the file recently, it's possible that the content is cached either on your device (so you can delete the app and reinstall it again) or it is cached in Apples CDN network (in which case you can activate an alternate mode as [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains#Add-the-Associated-Domains-Entitlement-to-Your-App)

If the "Would you like to save this password" dialog is not appearing, you either didn't correctly setup "Associated Domains" or the iOS heuristic did not detect a relevant change in your screens.

Comment: Wow this feels overly complicated compared to Android's AutofillManager.commit() function call.